# Javascript / jQuery Invert regex programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to automatically remove all characters which don't match with a pattern in an input. I tried it first using "^" (Example: "[a-z]{2,2}" will be converted to "[^a-z]*") but that just worked for some inputs.

Here's my code:

```
$("input:not([ignore-pattern-check])[pattern]").on("input", function(){
                let val = $(this).val();

                if (val.length >= 1){
                    var regex = $(this).attr("pattern");

                    if (regex.charAt(0) == "^"){
                        regex = regex.substr(1, regex.length);
                    }

                    if (regex.charAt(regex.length - 1) == "$"){
                        regex = regex.substr(0, regex.length - 1);
                    }

                    regex = regex.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/, "*");

                    regex = "^(?!.*(" + regex + "))$";

                    let reg = new RegExp(regex);

                    if (reg.test(val)){
                        alert("This char isn't allowed!");
                    } else {
                        _hide_message();
                    }

                    $(this).val(val.replace(reg, ""));
                }
            });
```

*EDIT*
Example:
I have a input with `pattern="^[a-z]*$"`. When I type now type a "A" (case sensitive), this "A" should automatically be removed from the value. When I type a "a" it should not be removed.

Comment: Try like this: `$(this).val(val.split(/your_pattern/).join(""))` instead of the whole `if` block.

Comment: Doesn't work. I changed it to this: `$(this).val(val.split(/$(this).attr("pattern")/).join(""))`.

Comment: I suggested using the *regex* pattern inside `.split`, not some code inside the delimiters. `$(this).val(val.split($(this).attr("pattern")).join(""))` *if `$(this).attr("pattern")` is a `RegExp` object*. If `$(this).attr("pattern")` is not a RegExp object, use `new RegExp($(this).attr("pattern"))`.

Comment: The pattern `^[a-z]$` means 1 lowercase letter so `AB` is invalid, if you reverse it you should be able to enter `AB` shouldn't you?

Comment: I wish you could explain it in simpler terms. Trying to hold the mega-regex info in my head then having to decipher what you mean on top of it is a little too much.

Comment: @Toto Sorry, I meant `[a-z]`. I made a quick example.

Comment: You can't "inverse" any pattern in a universal way. What I suggested is valid for simple non-anchored patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below - works using the solution from comment above.

```js
const update = () => {
  const regex = document.getElementById("regex").value;
  const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const result = input.match(new RegExp(regex, 'g')).join('X');
  console.log("result", result);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<label for="regex">Regex</label><input name="regex" id="regex" type="text" value="[a-z ]+"><br>
<label for="input">Input</label><input name="input" id="input" type="text" value="only Small Letters allowed, no _ underscores etc:)"><br>
<button onclick="update()">Run</button>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I think I did not express myself very well, so I made an edit. This doesn't work for me. Sorry.

Comment: Made a small update - dont know if it makes a difference though